# How to pad a Scala collection for minimum size?

Tags: scala

How to make sure a `Seq` is of certain minimum length, in Scala?

The below code does what I want (adds empty strings until `arr` has three entries), but it feels clumsy.

```
scala> val arr = Seq("a")
arr: Seq[String] = List(a)

scala> arr ++ Seq.fill(3-arr.size)("")
res2: Seq[String] = List(a, "", "")
```

A way to fulfill this would be a merger of two sequences: take from first, but if it runs out, continue from second. What was such method called...?

Comment: What do you Need that for? Can't you just use and array, with fixed length?

Comment: Likely I can, good point. It's input from a Google API that cuts away tails if spreadsheet cells are empty. I'd like to pad them back to empty strings, before processing.

Comment: Arrays have padding. @thomas-böhm If you wish to provide your take on that as an answer, I'll gladly pick it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
arr.padTo(3,"")
```

It was too trivial.

Answer (score 2):

I find this slightly better:

```
scala> (arr ++ Seq.fill(3)("")).take(3)
res4: Seq[String] = List(a, "", "")
```

---

And even better, thanks @thomas-böhm

```
scala> arr.toArray.padTo(3,"")
res5: Array[String] = Array(a, "", "")
```

Comment: How about replacing `Seq.fill(3)` with an infinite stream?

Comment: Care to suggest the proper syntax for one?

Comment: This works: `(arr.view ++ Stream.continually("")).take(3).force` (Not pretty. I don't recommend it.)

Comment: Thanks. I think the array `padTo` is the way to go, though.

Comment: No reason to convert to an `Array` before calling `padTo`.

Comment: @KarlBielefeldt You are right, and it makes my whole Q fall into the "how on Earth did I not see the..." category. :/